# Altair will not display chart in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, altair

Receiving the following error when trying to display an interactive network + bar graph using Altair and nx_altair:

*Javascript Error: Duplicate signal name: "selector003_x_1"
This usually means there's a typo in your chart specification. See the javascript console for the full traceback.*

I used the following code:

```
# Create interactive chart that couples network diagram with barplot of 'weights' of each node
# Weights refer to the number of links, or how many times a specific hashtag is used.

# Create a brush for the weights
edges = chart.layer[0]
nodes = chart.layer[1]

brush = alt.selection_interval(encodings=['x', 'y'])
color = alt.condition(brush, alt.value('orange'), alt.value('lightgrey'))

nodes = nodes.encode(fill=alt.condition(brush, alt.value('orange'), alt.value('lightgray'))).add_selection(brush).properties(width=800, height=800)

edges = edges.encode(stroke=alt.condition(brush, alt.value('orange'), alt.value('lightgray'))).add_selection(brush).properties(width=800, height=800)


# Create a bar chart for the weights that updates based on the brush
bar = alt.Chart(nodes.data).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('weight:Q', scale=alt.Scale(type='log'), title='Weight'),
    y=alt.Y('text:N', sort='-x', title='Hashtag'),
    color=color,
    tooltip=['weight:Q', 'text:N']
).transform_filter(brush).properties(
    width=800,
    height=800
)


chart2 = nodes + edges | bar

chart2
```

I tried running the same thing in VScode and it works from there, but not with google colab. Is there something with colab I don't understand in regards to JavaScript runtime?